# How to get a statistics for specific notification sent on Facebook via PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I need to retrieve `app_notification_clicks` and `app_notification_impressions` for every notification that my app sends. But all `Graph API` returns is some dummy statistics like so: [image]

I don't need statistics within one hour, but for every single notification. This is how my call looks now:

```
/{app-id}/app_insights/app_notification_clicks
```

But I think I would get better and more accurate results with something like this:

```
/{notification-id}/insights/clicks
```

If it would only exist. And I see here:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/notification/
messing with some `notification-id` stuff but I don't know how to retrieve notification id when I send one. Please help, this Graph API is killing me.